# How to return elements of a list as variables?

Tags: python, list, variables, element

I have a complex variable like the one below...

```
test_list[[test1, test1_var1, test1,var2], [test2, test2_var1]]
```

I have written a function to extract the variables from the desired test, see below...

```
def find_test(test_list, search_term):
    for index in range(len(test_list)):
        if test_list[index][0] == search_term:
            return test_list[index][1:]
```

This returns something like the following...

```
[test1_var1, test1_var2]
```

I would like to be able to return the variables as individual variables and not elements of a list. How would I go about doing this? How do I return variable number of variables? (sort of like *args but for return instead of arguments)

Comment: Are there always two values `return`ed?

Comment: Just join the list elements into a string: `return ' '.join([test1_var1, test1_var2])`

Comment: @jonrsharpe Sorry I should have made it clearer. I would like to have the flexibility of returning any number of variables.

Comment: @joemar.ct These variables will contain numeric values and will have arithmetic performed on them. So they can't be placed in a string.

Comment: Then I would say leave them in the list or convert to a dictionary (where the keys are the "variable names" and the values are the variables).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

actually you can do what you want, by using a list:

```
def find_test(test_list, search_term):
    for index in range(len(test_list)):
        if test_list[index][0] == search_term:
            return test_list[index][1:]
```

the destructuring array syntax is there for you:

```
foo, bar = find_text(x, y)
```

if you want to get the result as a list you can:

```
l = find_text(x,y)
```

if you want to get only one element:

```
foo, _ = find_text(x,y)
_, bar = find_text(x,y)
```

if you like to read, here are a few resources:

- https://docs.python.org/release/1.5.1p1/tut/tuples.html
- http://robert-lujo.com/post/40871820711/python-destructuring

Answer (score 2):

In python, **returning multiple variables corresponds to returning any iterable**, so there's no practical difference between returning a list or "multiple variables":

```
def f():
    return 1,2
def g():
    return [1,2]
a,b=f()
c,d=g()
```

The only difference  between these two functions is that `f` returns a tuple, and `g` returns a list - which is indifferent, if you use multiple assignment on the return value.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the built-in filter and expand the results in your function call:

```
def search(haystack, needle):
    return filter(lambda x: x[0] == needle, haystack)[0][1:]

a,b = search(test_list, 'test1')
```

Keep in mind if your result is more than two items, the above will fail.